# C# Repository - How to interact with other repositories

Tags: c#, asp.net, repository-pattern

I am in the process of refactoring some code, and extracting some methods that perform database CRUD operations into their own repository class.

I have a few questions, given the following two types of objects stored in the database:  Users and Roles

1. Should I create IUserRepository and IRoleRepository?
2. When doing something like assigning a User a Role, where should that method (AssignRoleToUser) live?  In IUserRepository or IRoleRepository?
3. If I want to add some more complex logic, let's say, IUserRepository.AddUserAndRoles takes an IUser, but also takes an array of IRole,
   should IUserRepository get an IRoleRepository injected into it?

Comment: why should there be so many repository, can't there only be one?

Comment: @LeiYang That is a good question.  I am not sure what best practice is.  I didn't want my code to get bloated with a ton of methods.

Comment: I'm not expert. but i think you can learn something from entity framework, there's only one dbcontext for one database, and that's enough.

Comment: The business logic should reside in Service. What you need is a service class which is dependent on these repositories and retrieve data from them, performs complex logic and saves data back to the repositories. Repositories dependent on each other must be the last option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1.Should I create IUserRepository and IRoleRepository?

Do you need to perform operations on `Users` and `Roles`? If yes, create both. If you do not need both but may need it in the future, then do not create it but only create it once you need it.

> 2.When doing something like assigning a User a Role, where should that method (AssignRoleToUser) live? In IUserRepository or IRoleRepository?

When you assing a role to a user, most likely you will add a user to the role. Therefore, it is more readable if the method is in the `Role` repository.

> 3.If I want to add some more complex logic, let's say, IUserRepository.AddUserAndRoles takes an IUser, but also takes an array of IRole, should IUserRepository get an IRoleRepository injected into it?

Use a layer on top which will interact with both `User` and `Role` repository and do the complex work there.

Try not to return `IQueryable`(s) from your repository-however, keep in mind there are two schools of thought on this. But you will thank me if you ever have to replace one of your operations by a stored procedure for performance reasons or if you introduce a soft delete flag. If you do not expose `IQueryable`(s), you will make the change in your repository. But if you exposed it, you will need to find all the queries and change them everywhere. People forget that when they write a query in Linq (to EF or SQL), they are still writing queries but the only difference is they are writing them in C#. If they were writing them in SQL, they will think twice about writing them all over the place.

Another note, do not start with the classic CRUD, FindAll etc. in all your repositories. I have seen many repositories written like that and then I ask the question: But we do not delete orders so why do we have a delete in the `Order` repository? Make sure your repositories reflect the operations you perform on the objects. If all you need is an `R` (out of CRUD), then just create a `Read` method. If you need find, then add that to it. Add methods as you need them. Do not write code if you don't need it yet.

Comment: Thank you for your response!  I was hoping I was on the right path, and was considering this.  My main drive is being able to test the business logic layer by mocking up the repositories.  Part of my database is controlled by Entity Framework, then there are some other tables that aren't part of EF (additions) and are controlled by manual SQL scripts.  Do you recommend putting even the EF layer on repositories?

Comment: Yes because queries against EF are still queries. Some people will not agree but most likely they are working on one-off applications. But again, I do not want to start a war here so to each their own. But yes, since you are asking me, I say yes. I always do this myself too unless I am doing a POC or a short-lived app.